# Add ClientIP to xhr post request

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, ip

My ErrorHandler can catch the error, but i cant add the client ip. Im not used to ajax, xhr, ... and im still learning javascript.
I get following output in my backend:
`ERROR {"timestamp":"2020-10-12T22:14:57.113Z","ip":{"readyState":1},"message":"Error in mounted hook: \"ReferenceError: asd is not defined}`

Why do i get `"ip":{"readyState":1}` and how do i get my real ip?

```js
      window.onerror = function(timestamp, ip, 
           message, source, lineno, colno, error) {

           const toSend ={
           "timestamp": new Date(),
           "ip":  $.get('https://ipinfo.io/ip', 
           function(dataIP){
              return {
                dataIP
              }    
          }),
          "message": message,
          "source": source,
          "lineo": lineno,
          "colno": colno,
          "error":error,
         };
        
        const jsonString = JSON.stringify(toSend);
          
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        
        xhr.open("POST",
        "http://localhost:8090/api/auth/event");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", 
        "application/json");
        xhr.send(jsonString);
      
        return false;
      };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.get` is an asynchronous function therefore it doesn't return the IP address. Instead you need to wrap your xhr call within the `$.get` function.

```js
window.onerror = function(timestamp, ip, message, source, lineno, colno, error) {
    $.get('https://ipinfo.io/ip', function(dataIP){
            const toSend = {
                "timestamp": new Date(),
                "ip": dataIP,
                "message": message,
                "source": source,
                "lineo": lineno,
                "colno": colno,
                "error":error,
            };
    
            const jsonString = JSON.stringify(toSend);
      
            const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    
            xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost:8090/api/auth/event");
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            xhr.send(jsonString); 
    });
  
    return false;
};
```

`$.get` is probably [jQuery.get](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) which returns a jqXHR object which is why it says `readyState`.

Another thing to note is that since `$.get` is jQuery you probably can also use [`$.post`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) for your `xhr` call. Also, depending on where `$.post` is being submitted, the ip address could be added by the server instead of on the frontend.